# Immatrikulation and PhD in Germany

Tags: phd, germany, europe, administration

Do PhD students (who work as research/teaching assistant and get paid according to the TV-L E13 bracket) in Germany get an official student enrollment from the university 'Immatrikulation'?

Comment: Please search this site thoroughly - this has almost certainly been asked (and answered) before. As a starting point try e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=Germany+E13 . The generic answer is yes, and yes, but it need not hold universally, so if you want a specific answer then you need to provide further details about your situation.

Answer (score 5):

Depends. At my university in Germany, you could choose yourself if you want to enroll or not. Some enrolled, e.g. for the cheap bus ticket and student lunches, other didn't. But there is no general rule for that, every university or even every institute might have its own regulations.